# How to display PopUp ShowMessage on Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, popup, firemonkey, messagebox

How do I display a `MessageBox` or `ShowMessage` popup dialog on a [DelphiFMX Python App](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python)?

I basically want a `Form` with a `Button` and when you press on the button, then there should be a popup like this:

[image: MessageBox Popup in Python GUI App]

I have a button click event, but I have no idea what to put in there to display such a Message popup. I have the following code currently:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 800
        self.Height = 500

        self.myButton = Button(self)
        self.myButton.Parent = self
        self.myButton.Position.X = 100
        self.myButton.Position.Y = 100
        self.myButton.Width = 200
        self.myButton.Height = 200
        self.myButton.Text = "Click me"

        self.myButton.OnClick = self.myButtonClick

    def myButtonClick(self, sender):
        print('Button Clicked!')


def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

What do I write in the `myButtonClick` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
DialogService.ShowMessage("Hello World")
```

Here's a screenshot showing it working on a button click:

[image: Button Click and ShowMessage in Python GUI App]